# How to write the validator for a model field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, ip

I have Django model like this:

```
class Host():
    ipv4 = models.ChaField(max_length=39,verbose_name=_("IPv4"), validator= [ip_validator])
    ipv6 = models.CharField(max_length=39, verbose_name=_("IPv6"), 
                        blank=True, null=True, validators= [ip_validator])
```

And i defined the ip_validator method in utils.py:

```
 from netaddr import * 
 def ip_validator(value):
 try:
     ip_version = IPAddress(value).version()
     if ip_version !=6:
         raise ValidationError(u'%s Not a  IPv6 address' % value)
 except ValueError:
     raise ValidationError(u'%s Not a IPv6 address' % value)
```

It works fine but i have to written the same method for IPv4 validation. It seems to be redundancy and not a good idea. Would it be possible to write generic method for both IPv4 and IPv6.

I found a following sample to do it but not able to understand How it is passing the parameter to validator:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 class IPAddress(object):
     def __init__(self, version):
         self.version = version

 def validator_factory(ip_version):
     def validate_ip_address(ip_address):
         if ip_address.version != ip_version:
             print "Invalid! :("
         else:
             print "Valid! :D"
     return validate_ip_address

 ipv4_validator = validator_factory(4)
 ipv6_validator = validator_factory(6)

 ipv4_address = IPAddress(4)
 ipv6_address = IPAddress(6)

 ipv4_validator(ipv4_address)
 ipv4_validator(ipv6_address)
 ipv6_validator(ipv6_address)
```

If it is doing in this way then what we have to pass in the `validator = []`

**UPDATED!**
in models.py:

```
 class Host():
     ipv4 = models.CharField(max_length=39,verbose_name=_("IPv4 address"),
                        validators=[validator_factory(4)])
```

is this the right way to call validators?
and in utils.py:

```
from netaddr import *

def validator_factory(ip_version):
    def validate_ip_address(ipv4):
        if IPAddress(ipv4).version != ip_version:
           print "Invalid! :("
        else:
           print "Valid! :D"
    return validate_ip_address
```

What is the wrong here?

Comment: Django 1.4 has a built in [`GenericIPPAddressField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#genericipaddressfield). Using the `protocol` argument you can accept IPv4, IPv6 or both types of addresses.

Comment: @Alasdair but i am using Django 1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `validator_factory` works because of the closure of the `ip_version` variable. The inner function returned by factory has access to the `ip_version` variable. You would use the 
`ipv4_validator` or `ipv6_validator` function in the validators list for your field.

I would recommend upgrading to Django 1.4 if possible, so that you can use  or the [`GenericIPAddressField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#genericipaddressfield). If you need to stick with version 1.3, you could backport the code from Django 1.4. If you stick with your own validators, I wouldn't worry about duplication too much, just focus on getting two validators that work.

Comment: I am not able to understand the solution. WOuld you please paste the sudo code over here for passing the data to validator. I am facing a problem how should i pass the ip_version and ip_Address bothe from the model field in validator. Because we can pass only one parameter from there.

Comment: Look at the updated part in code. i tried with this situation but nothing happens (see the updated section in question)

Comment: You are using the validators argument correctly in your field definition. However your validator does not raise any validation errors so it won't do anything. I'm afraid I can't help you debug your validators. There are already perfectly good ones [included in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#validate-ipv4-address), (IPv4 in Django 1.2+, IPv6 in Django 1.4+), so I recommend you use them.